# How to get an array instead of object when requesting JSON data using HTTPful

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest, httpful

I'm using [HTTPful](http://phphttpclient.com/) to send some requests in PHP and get data in JSON, but the library is converting the result into objects, where I want the result to be an array. In other words, its doing a `json_decode($data)` rather than `json_decode($data, true)`.

There is, *somewhere*, an option to use the latter, but I can't figure out where. The option was added in v0.2.2:

```
- FEATURE Add support for parsing JSON responses as associative arrays instead of objects
```

But I've been reading [documentation](http://phphttpclient.com/docs/) and even [the source](https://github.com/nategood/httpful/tree/master/src/Httpful), and I don't see the option anywhere... The only way I can think of is making my own [`MimeHandlerAdapter`](http://phphttpclient.com/docs/class-Httpful.Handlers.MimeHandlerAdapter.html) which does a `json_decode($data, true)` but it seems like a pretty backwards way of doing it if there is an option somewhere...

Comment: I suggested an improvement to this https://github.com/nategood/httpful/issues/151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a little late to answer this, but I did a little research while using Httpful and found the answer.  Httpful uses a default set of handlers for each mime type.  If one is registered before you send the request, it will use the one you registered.  Conveniently, there is an `Httpful\Handlers\JsonHandler` class.  The constructor takes an array of arguments.  The only one it uses is `$decode_as_array`.  Therefore, you can make it return an array like this:

```
// Create the handler
$json_handler = new Httpful\Handlers\JsonHandler(array('decode_as_array' => true));
// Register it with Httpful
Httpful\Httpful::register('application/json', $json_handler);
// Send the request
$response = Request::get('some-url')->send();
```

## UPDATE

I realized that it sometimes parses the response into a funky array if you don't tell the request to expect JSON.  The docs say it's supposed to work automagically, but I was having some issues with it.  Therefore, if you get weird output, try explicitly telling the request to expect JSON like so:

```
$response = Request::get('some/awesome/url')
    ->expects('application/json')
    ->send();
```

Comment: its not obvious from the auto-generated documentation because the variable is just called $args http://phphttpclient.com/docs/source-class-Httpful.Handlers.JsonHandler.html#9

Answer (score 2):

I never used this library. But in a research I found that you can find this option at src/Httpful/Handlers/JsonHandler.php on line 11.

There you will see:

```
private $decode_as_array = false;
```

And this flag is used at the same file on line 27:

```
$parsed = json_decode($body, $this->decode_as_array);
```

Comment: but how can i use this option apart from modifying the librarys source code

Comment: I don't know how your library exactly works. So, another developer probably can help you better than me. But I think if you change the privilege of $decode_as_array to public, you can manipulate it in the two ways freely.

Comment: I'm also annoyed by same issue, so I filter `$response->body` with a function named `stdclass_to_array`: https://gist.github.com/kaorukobo/9267221#file-stdclass_to_array_with_json_encode_decode_for_httpful-php

Answer (score 1):

You have to set **decode_as_array** to **true** value, to do this:

```
\Httpful\Httpful::register(\Httpful\Mime::JSON, new \Httpful\Handlers\JsonHandler(array('decode_as_array' => true)));
```

before *Request::get* calling